# Xcode problem with certifacte when I change the computer

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, signing

I am write IOS app with my friend computer using Xcode and when I try to update my app with another computer I got this message "Missing private key for signing certificate.
Failed to locate the private key matching certificate "iPhone Distribution: Khaled Hussein (2.......M4)" in the keychain. To sign with this signing certificate, install its private key in your keychain. If you don't have the private key, select a different signing certificate for CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY in the build settings editor."

Answer (score 0):

You must add or get an existing certification here "https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates"
[image]